# set the name of html input code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Im trying to set the name of a radio button that I generated from the code behind. I cant get it to work. Any ideas?

How i did it:

```
   protected void repProductsDatabound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs  e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

            Enums.ProductCode product = (Enums.ProductCode)e.Item.DataItem;
            HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();

            HtmlTableCell buttonCell = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlInputButton btn = new HtmlInputButton("radio");
            btn.Name = "productsRadioGroup";
          //  btn.ServerClick += onProductSelectionChanged;
            buttonCell.Controls.Add(btn);
            row.Controls.Add(buttonCell);


            HtmlTableCell ProductCell = new HtmlTableCell();
            ProductCell.InnerText = product.ToString().Replace("_", " ");
            row.Controls.Add(ProductCell);

            e.Item.Controls.Add(row);

        }

    }
```

result

```
<td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$repProducts$ctl01$ctl02" type="radio" /></td>
        <td>Be Business</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$repProducts$ctl02$ctl02" type="radio" /></td>
        <td>Be BusinessLite</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="ctl00$MainContent$repProducts$ctl03$ctl02" type="radio" /></td>
    <td>Be BusinessPro</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Why are you dynamically adding controls to the page within a repeater's OnItemDataBound event? This is circumventing the entire functionality of a repeater.

Comment: try     btn.Attributes.Add("name", "your_name");

Comment: The "name" attribute is clearly being overwritten by ASP.NET's naming convention. I don't think setting this attribute at any point before it is added to the page is going to make a difference. Tom Squires why don't you tell us what it is that you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: MoarCodePlz : Im trying to have a radio button group. They all need to have the same name so only one can be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you cant set the name of radio buttons in a repeater. Its a known bug  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495